# ajax calls are stacking

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So the Title kind of says what happens. I have one ajax call and if it is successful it sends out another one, but the problem is before the one has finished it has sent out another one, and the ajax start stacking. Im **not** using async, and using **php** for my server language. My ajax also has a timeout of 5 seconds = 5000 milliseconds.
So its polling the server and while that is happening its waiting and then the javascript does a new ajax call, even before the other one has come back with information.

So this is my jquery ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
                url: ("json/getfriends.php"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: {friendlist: friendsarray},
                async: false,
                timeout: 5000,  
                dataType: 'json',       
                success: function(data){                
                    $.each(data, function(i, val){
                        friendsarray.push(val);                 
                    });
                    setTimeout("friends();", 15000); //loops the ajax call

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    if (errorThrown['code'] == 101){
                        //time out, not data was received 
                        setTimeout("friends();", 15000); //loops the ajax call
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                }
            });
```

SO my question is how to either stop the ajax stacking on top of each other or how make one ajax call go only once the other call brings back data.

[so here is a image](http://grubber.co.nz/stackexchange/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-16%20at%2010.39.48%20AM.PNG)
[and the aftermath](http://grubber.co.nz/stackexchange/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-16%20at%2011.00.43%20AM.PNG)

[my full javascript](http://grubber.co.nz/developer/_social_development/js/chat.js)

Comment: where are your other ajax calls? , or what is calling this repeaditly

Comment: where is code for `friends()`?? Sounds like you have another `setInterval` or something running as well. Also poor practice passing string to `setTimeout`

Comment: I think need to post some more of the code.  I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: @charlietfl this is the code that is in the `friends();` function and this is the only one aka, its the only one thats activating the function

Comment: How is the function called?  A button click? Or just programmatically?

Comment: @NicholasE. programmatically when the page loads it will start the function and start the loop

Comment: how do you know it is `stacking`? Code above should work fine assuming `friends` only includes this ajax code. What happens to `friendsarray`  you aren't consuming it in the above code??

Comment: @charlietfl look at the image i put a link to, this is what starts to happen and the list just keeps increasing

Comment: The image shows it's stuck on `checkchat.php`, but that's not this code is it?

Comment: I can't think of what could be happening, but I suggest saving a reference to the timeout ex: myTimeout = setTimeout(...) then clearing it before refreshing ex: clearTimeout(myTimeout).  It's kind of sloppy though, but may solve the problem.

Comment: @Jack get usually get suck at both of them.

Comment: @NicholasE. I chucked up a link to my full js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line is, the code you've shown doesn't exhibit the issue.

However, the [full JavaScript](http://grubber.co.nz/developer/_social_development/js/chat.js) you've added has a major issue:

```
...
setTimeout(chat_check(), 20000);    
...
```

See that? It immediately runs `chat_check()` from within the success handler. Not a good idea!

It should be this:

```
setTimeout(chat_check, 20000);
```

It passes the function reference as the first argument, rather than the function result. You might want to apply the same for your `friends()` call:

```
setTimeout(friends, 15000);
```

**Edit**

Btw, I'm not sure why you're using `async: false`, but doing so isn't very nice for the user experience as the browser will be unresponsive during the request.

It's better with the default asynch mode :)

Comment: yer thanks, ill give it ago and yer I just wanted to see how well the async: false works, it works fine except for this point where the requests just stack :-(

Comment: Isn't calling the function with a timeout making the entire call asynchronous anyways?

But yea, setTimeout(chat_check(), 20000);  is definitely the problem, especially since it's made inside the same function...  Never-ending recursion.

Comment: @ryanc1256 In most cases you don't want `async: false`, **especially** when the request takes a while and it starts to affect the site's handling.

Comment: @NicholasE. I'm talking about the asynchronous nature of the request, not how the function itself is called.

Comment: Thanks @jack it worked, even thought Im changing my code back so Ill use async true :-D